# How to split email addresses between 2 separate email servers?

Tags: email-server, email

I currently have my small business's mail hosted with an external provider, which is fine, however they only offer 5 emails under the current plan. I don't want to pay extra for an additional 5, and I have a Synology NAS that can run a mail server quite happily. As the additional mail addresses are going to be used for non-critical staff, is there a way to have the extra mail addresses hosted by the internal mail server, and the existing mail addresses hosted by the external provider?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have admin access to DNS or Email server.

Comment: Your title is misleading and does not correct tell what you want! I edited your title.

Comment: I assume that NAS will have a dynamic IP. Imagine what happens, between your NAS receiving a new IP address, and the changed DDNS entry propagating to everyone: your mails will tried to be delivered to the old address, on which, somebody might be happy to accept them. Don't operate a mail server on a dynamic address.

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea to run your own email server, if have done it before, like 18 years ago when it was expensive, and it requieres a lot of effort better expend other way. Email accounts are really cheap now.

But, yes you can do the following:

1. Create a new MX entry in DNS using a new FQDN name like: nc.mydomain.com (nc is non critical, but could be whatever you want). The idea is to have a more specific/different address.
2. Point the new MX record to your NAS public IP (I imagine it will be a DDNS entry or the fixed IP from your Internet router).
3. Configure your NAS to handle mail for domain nc.mydomain.com and it's mailboxes user1@nc.mydomain.com.
4. Make sure to secure your setup, email servers are common targets of attacks and smart hosts used for SPAM distribution when not properly configured.
5. Test your email routing from/to different providers. Internet public IP blocks intended for broadband access (your router IP) are usually disallowed to host SMTP servers and you might find problems and your IP listed in public databases of offending or not authorized IPs.
6. Think again about the pros and cons from running your own SMTP server!

Comment: 7: think about what it means to operate a mail server on a dynamically changing ip address

Answer (score 0):

If you've already exhausted the 5 addresses/mailboxes (you don't state which) they gave you, then you can't add more addresses/mailboxes with the current setup.

In case they do allow you to add more addresses (not mailboxes), you could forward new addresses to your own server, which needs to have an MX or an A record in order to receive mail.

If not, there is no easy solution; you'd have to register a domain, set up your own mail server, and forward the old addresses to the mail provider (or not; no idea why you'd want to do that if you have to run your own mail server anyway.)

I would strongly advise against running your own mail server unless there is no other solution available - and there obviously is: just request more addresses from the mail provider.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow-up adaptr**

Yes, e-mails and mailboxes are different entities, you have to elaborate, 5 "what" they provide, and can you have (and manage) "virtual" e-mails without separate mailboxes

**Short answer**

No, each **location** inside domain have **one final MX destination**.

**Tricks**

1. Note mentioned by me *location*. You can add @some.domain as addition to @domain and define separate MX for @some.domain
2. Note mentioned by me "final destination". You (hired skilled postmaster-hostmaster is better choice) can add secondary MX for domain with bigger priority - it this case undelivered to primary MX mails will be delivered to backup MX, from which you can collect messages in queue using ETRN|ATRN capable MTA|MUA
3. You (hired skilled postmaster-hostmaster is better choice) can play with SRV records (_smtp._tcp) weight field for some type of (maybe implementable) load balancing for SMTP-in instead of old good MX... No warranties!!!